# Google Tag Manger - Data Layer Variables - Explaination of Duplicate Set of Values

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, enhanced-ecommerce

[image: Image GTM Preview Mode - Window Loaded - Data Layer]

Can someone explain to me what I am looking at?

I hope this is not a duplicate push of the same data.

Comment: It's clearly not duplicate - see lines 16-17 and lines 80-81.

Comment: ok thank you!! ... can you give me a break down what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Badly formulated question, but I am going to help you anyway.

What you are looking at is probably what is called a [product impression in the Enhanced eCommerce report](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#impression-data) of Google Analytics.

They are pushing an array of object into the dataLayer so that they could be sent in your product list performance report.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The link also helped.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not a duplicate set of data. What is happening is that you have setup a data push which sends a list of all related products to your data layer. So if you need to see which were the related products shown when a customer viewed a particular products detail page, you would have a list of these products showing up in GA. Shout if you have more questions

Comment: Is it fair to say the first set is the data on the page and the second set is the push of that data to GA?